# How to enable button based on gridview value?

Tags: c#, button, gridview

I have a column in SQL:

Status

open
Close

and Gridview with Boundfield value='Status'

When a user selects a row and the Status == open then it should display a button. Otherwise ist hiden.

```html
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 string y = Data.Rows[GridView1.SelectedIndex][5].ToString();

 if (y == "open")
 {
  btnAccept.Visible = true;
 }
 else
 {
  btnAccept.Visible = false;
 }
}
```

```html
 <asp:Button Text="Accept" OnClick="btnAccept_Click"  Visible="false" ID="btnAccept" runat="server" />
```

Comment: And the question is???

Comment: It does not work. The Button is always enabled. Even if visible = true

Comment: Visibility has nothing to do with the button being Enabled or Disabled.  Use the Enabled Property of the Button: `btnAccept.Enabled = (y == "open");` Also, if you haven't already, consider styling disabled buttons with CSS  `input[type=button][disabled], ...  {cursor:not-allowed;}`

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code like this

```
string y = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[5].Text;
```

Comment: It throws an error: object' does not contain a definition for 'Text' and no extension method 'Text' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 0):

This could be the solution:

```
string y = GriView1.SelecteRows[0].Cells[5].Value.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's counter-intuitive, but GridView1.SelectedRow is not set until after SelectedIndexChanged completes.

Also visibility has nothing to do with the button being Enabled or Disabled. 
Use the Enabled Property of the Button:

```
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  GridView gv = (GridView) sender ;
  btnAccept.Enabled = (gv.Rows[ gv.SelectedIndex ].Cells[5].Text == "open"); 
}
```

Also, if you haven't already, consider styling disabled buttons with CSS:

```
input[type=button][disabled], 
button[disabled] 
{
    cursor:not-allowed;
}
```